# Triggering a folder action when a file is renamed

Tags: applescript, automator

I know I can trigger actions when a specific file is added to a folder, but I like to do the same when a file is renamed, e.g. remotely (Dropbox, etc)
How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Sorry pal, thank you very much for the suggestion... I did not know fswatch. Next would be 'how do I use the logs from fswatch', I saw that even when removing a file the log is for Renaming. Nonetheless, how do I pipe the events into automator/applescript?

Comment: It kind of depends what you want to do in Applescript - it is quite easy, but probably even easier in `bash`. Can you give an outline of what needs doing? Also, when you delete a file using `Finder`, it doesn't actually delete it, instead it moves it to the Trash which is a rename from `$HOME/Dropbox` to `$HOME/.Trash`.

Comment: My intent would be to trigger a split pdf action (into separated pages) when a file is being received on a specific folder. I have the first part (split action), but can't make it with the latter. Also, moving to a second folder would be better, because even single pages trigger the action recursively...

Comment: I have updated my answer - please have another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Here is a little script that will fire Applescript to display a dialog box every time any file changes in your current directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
fswatch -x . | while read f; do
   osascript <<EOF
tell application "System Events" to display dialog "$f"
EOF
done
```

So, you would save it as `monitor`, then make it executable (only necessary once) with:

```
chmod +x monitor
```

and run it with:

```
./monitor
```

You will see that it fires Applescript each time with the name of any files that change in your directory.

**Original Answer**

You can maybe use `fswatch`. I install it with [homebrew](http://brew.sh), using:

```
brew install fswatch
```

Then you can run `fswatch` on your Dropbox account like this:

```
fswatch -x -r ~/Dropbox
```

and it will print a line each time anything happens in your Dropbox and you can pass that to a script for processing.

Here are a couple of examples:

[image]

and

[image]